# Typical Tensorflow model training time?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am creating some of my own CNN graphs in tensorflow, but the training time is extremely slow. For a small (<30) sized batch of imagenet images, it takes several seconds for a single training iteration. 
Has anyone trained any substantial models such as VGG or Inception on Tensorflow? How long does a single batch take to run through the network in a training forward and backprop pass?

Also, does anyone have any insight into general causes for slow training?

Comment: Are you using a GPU?

Comment: Yes, a pretty good GPU

Comment: Can you check if tensflow is using it? Use device placement - https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html

Comment: Yes, tensorflow is using the GPU. My model is rather convoluted so I was wanted to compare with other large models on training time.